# Difference of tracert and pathping

Tags: icmp

What is the difference between **tracert** and **pathping** command? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://www.freeccnaworkbook.com/blog/ccna/ping-vs-traceroute-vs-pathping) you can find detailed comparison of ping, tracert and pathping.

> **PING**, is an application based on the ICMP protocol which is used to
>   send echo packets to a destination and expecting to receive an echo
>   response and it calculates the RTT (Round Trip Time) from when the
>   packet was sent to when the echo response was received. Generally when
>   using PING on a LAN network you can trust that what it is saying is
>   accurate unless you have foreknowledge of network devices in the
>   transit path that prioritize ICMP over mission critical TCP/UDP
>   Traffic. This however is very common in networks that utilize unified
>   communications, meaning voice and data on the same network. This is
>   because QoS Policies are put in place to ensure voice traffic and
>   other mission critical traffic is prioritized over ICMP thus
>   indirectly affecting the RTT time of an ICMP ping test.
>
> **Trace-route** is another method commonly used by technicians and
>   engineers to diagnosis latency in the transit path however any
>   engineer that has studied how trace-route works would know that its
>   results are nearly always misleading.
>
> Trace-route works in a manner similar to ping however it uses the TTL
>   feature to make each successive hop in the transit path respond with
>   an ICMP TTL Expired packet. Thus gives you the ability to determine
>   which network devices the ICMP packet is traversing.
>
> When you dig deeper into the operation of traceroute you will see that
>   traceroute utilizes 3 probe packets for each successive hop by default
>   unless you specify other wise. Each probe packet indirectly measures
>   the latency between the source and the device where the TTL is
>   declared expired. This latency calculation is a by product of its true
>   intended purpose. Keep in mind even if you send probes to a device
>   that is five hops away, random latency spikes in any four devices
>   prior to the fifth hop can result in the fifth hop looking like it has
>   high latency.
>
> **Pathping** works first by doing a traceroute to the destination then it
>   uses ICMP to ping each hop in the transit path 100 times. This is used
>   to verify latency between the source and destination via icmp echo per
>   each hop. But remember what I said earlier, you cannot rely ICMP when
>   public devices are involved. So you can run into cases where you see
>   ICMP pings destined to one hop in the transit drop 40% of the traffic
>   whereas the next hop has 100% success rate. This is due to CoPP.
>
> Pathping in general is a much better tool to diagnosis latency from a
>   specific source to destination with a relative degree of accuracy.
>   Note that I said Relative, this is because latency is ALWAYS relative
>   to your location on the network.

Comment: Link-only answers are useless in the long run due to link rot. Please include the most relevant details in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

`tracert` uses fake UDP requests with short TTL and interprets returning ICMP messages to find out the routing hops, three attempts per hop.

`pathping` finds out the routing hops and then pings (ICMP echo request) each of them 100 times (default) to help locate packet dropping hops.

Depending on the hops, both outputs can look vastly different. The reality can be something else still.